# Create object in rails if request params present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a an json Api who received parameters to create a Device, like *name*, *imei*, etc. The Device can have one Blacklist object (`has_one :blacklist`). I would like to know what's the proper-way to create the blacklist object if a params is present in the post request of Device.

Exemple `curl -X POST -d api_key=000000 -d device[name]='stack' -d device[blacklist]='true' https://www.example.com/api/devices.json`

In the code for the moment I should have

```
def create
  @device = Device.new
  @device.update_attributes(strong_parameters)
  if params[:device]['blacklist'] && params[:device]['blacklist'] == true
      @blacklist = Blacklist.new(device_id: @device.id)
  end
  render :device, status: 201 # will render with jbuilder @device and @blacklist
end
```

But I don't like it that much :

1. Too much logic in one controller
2. Verifying parameters inside is a good practice?
3. If no parameters are given, how to handle the request? I know that strong parameters should return a 400, but what about `@device` I just created.

This controller smells for me.

Feedbacks welcome.

### The result when doing a PATCH

```
class DevicesController

  before_action :found_device, only: :blacklist # get `@device`
  before_action :blacklist_device, only: :blacklist

  def blacklist
    render :device, status: 200
  end

  private

  def blacklist_device
    if (params[:device]['blacklisted'] and
        params[:device]['blacklisted'] == true and
        @blacklist = BlacklistedDevice.create(device_id: @device.id, organisation_id: current_store.organisation.id))
      @device.reload
    else
      render json: { error: "Missing or incorrect 'blacklisted' parameter" }, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Is it mandatory to have a blacklist ? Also, a blacklist should normally contain some items...but you just send `true` ??

Comment: a blacklist object is created in database only if we have the parameters `device[blacklist]='true'`. We will only look for the `device_id` in the blacklist entry further.

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought your 3. was dealing with the blacklist object only. I'll add a reply.

Comment: Problems with your new implementation : multiple rendering, see [this nice article](http://blog.arkency.com/2014/07/4-ways-to-early-return-from-a-rails-controller/). `blacklist_device?`'s name ends with `?` but does not return a boolean. What you could do is only keep the if block, and move the rest of the code back to the `blacklist` action (return true only if @blacklist is saved).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Cyril.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Too much logic in the conrtoller ? No**

I have also heard a lot 'too much logic in the controller is bad' but this is bullshit or rather I believe the words are not accurate enough.

What that phrase means for me, is that for example, model validations should not be in the controller, and the controller should remain light for very basic REST actions. Controller should only be a bridge between the HTML request and the model. Think of it this way : you may have several controllers modifying the same model. What you would write in EVERY controller, should most likely instead be written in the model as a validation.

But here you're dealing with specific requests (transforming a `device[blacklist] == true` as a Blacklist Model isn't something "natural", so yes in my opinion it should be in the controller.

Plus, a controller action of just 6 lines isn't what we could call "too much logic"

**Verifying parameters inside is good Practice ? Yes/No**

I assume by that you mean writing specific lines of codes in the controller like `if params[xxx] == blabla` or something equivalent

The way you did was good. You use specific code only for the special parameter (the blacklist) and the rest of the params go into the model as strong params, so the model validations will do the rest.

Verify parameters only if it's relevant to this particular controller (for example, if it was site-based, you could probably use a different implementation of the blacklist so the difference would have to be in the controller.

**If no parameters are given, how to handle the request? I know that strong parameters should return a 400, but what about @device I just created.**

This the part I don't quite like about your current implementation. You don't check for the success of your `save` operations. Here's what you could have written (check the result of every persistence operation result, and render appropriately)

```
def create
  @device = Device.new
  if @device.update_attributes(strong_parameters)
    if (params[:device]['blacklist'] 
        and params[:device]['blacklist'] == true
        and @blacklist = Blacklist.create(device_id: @device.id))
      # Handle stuff when everything is cool
      render :device, status: 201 # will render with jbuilder @device and 
    else
      # Handle stuff when there's no blacklist param true
    end
  else
    # Handle error on model save
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Cyril for this well written answer. Will move part of my code in the model and add more errors handling.

Comment: Alright, but in the code you just showed us there's nothing to move in the model. The blacklist stuff, at least the way you handle it, should remain in the controller IMO. I prefer your solution for creating the blacklist to Axel's one personally.

Comment: I prefer too finally. It's probably easier to maintain. I will have to do the same when patching a device and remove the linked blacklist.

Comment: updated question with proposition. Love to hear your feedbacks.

Answer (score 1):

Inspecting `params` is well put in the controller - that's it's purpose - the model layer should not have knowledge of request parameters.

But you can put this info in a transient attribute with

```
class Device
  attr_accessor 'create_blacklisted'

end
```

Then you can create an input field for that new attribute and an `after_initialize` callback in the `Device` model as well that can subsequently create the Blacklist entry.

Comment: Nice tips Axel. Gonna try to implement this now mixing with the answer of Cyril

Comment: After thinking a little bit. It seems a little bit too much to put an after_initialize callback. I have more than 200.000 devices and less than 1000 blacklisted.  If it was more maybe I should use advice.